# What changes should I use for a Human with Type Outsider instead of Humanoid?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

For a particular campaign setting, my DM asked me to build a Human with type Outsider instead of Humanoid, because my character was born in another plane.
What changes should I apply to my character?

Comment: Huh? As in, the human race, but Outsider type instead of Humanoid? Or some kind of human native to the Outer Planes? Or..? What? Not really clear what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I'm a Humanoid native of another plane.

Comment: Are you clear on the differences between the Outsider type and the Extraplanar subtype?

Comment: Usually that sort of thing is handled just by using the standard Human class and saying they’re native to wherever. There are humans everywhere in D&D.

Comment: @KRyan : Well, my DM told me that I am an outsider, so for his rules I don't need to sleep and eat, moreover I cannot be raised if I get killed. I'd like to know if there's some other bonus.

Comment: @Ernir Not at all.

Comment: @IssamTP Are you an Outsider *and* a Human, so you get both sets of traits? Or just an Outsider that looks like a Human? It might be best to clarify a bit more with your DM.

Comment: IssamTP - Could you please add more details? What other plane (and do you have a choice?), are all the PCs Outsiders or just you? Any relevant details on the setting or your character concept? What is the motivation behind this requirement?

Comment: @Tridus Yes, I am a Human **AND** an Outsider.

Comment: @GoBLiN I have no informations about my plane, I guess the DM does not have any idea about it; the motivation is quite complicated to explain: in material plane, where all other characters come from, all deities are disappeared so, clerics have no power. To let us have an healer in party he told me to do this character that come from another world/plane.

Comment: IssamTP - in order to help us help you, you should edit your question to better represent what exactly you wish to know. For example, are you interested in "*What are the mechanical effects of changing a Human's type from* Humanoid *to* Outsider *?*" or "*How to build a Human PC native to a different plane?*" or even something like "*How to create a healer PC in a campaign where clerics have lost their powers?*" (the last one seems to me as the closest to your real problem - and there are other solutions to healing, such as playing a bard or a druid...)

Comment: Coming from another world is different from coming from another plane. Which is it? (Another world would be the same plane, and not make you and Outsider under any interpretation.)

Comment: @IssamTP, reading up on [Outsiders](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#outsiderType) and comparing them to [Extraplanars](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#extraplanarSubtype) may help you in rephrasing the question.